# What am I doing wrong while creating Image pyramid in geoserver?

Tags: gdal, geoserver, osgeo

I have geoserver 2.15.0 installed and I'm following these steps to create Image pyramid https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html I created all the tiles and now I have a 0 folder which has shape file and eveything, I also have .prj and .properties file, but When I'm trying to add a store, I get the following error : org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1@d978c9 on component [AjaxLink [Component id = link]] threw an exception
[image]

Comment: does geoserver have write permissions for that directory - depending on how you are running geoserver depends on which user needs ownership of that folder

Comment: I'm running geoserver on jetty, and the folder , I have pasted in data_dir .. how can I check if geoserver has permission

Comment: `ls -l` will list the directory contents and show you the owner and group permissions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the answer [HERE](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Server-error-when-trying-to-publish-an-image-pyramid-td5363465.html) and it worked. Basically, switch the `-co "COMPRESS=JPEG"` to `-co "COMPRESS=LZW"` when using gdal_retile.py